# How to understand which setup class do I need to use and what is it's purpose?

Tags: magento2

I just started to learn Magento 2 and I'm confused with all those setup classes (`eavSetup`, `categorySetup`, `Set` and so on).

Could someone explain me about those setup classes purposes and how should I know which setup class do I need to use? When should I use `eavSetup` or `categorySetup`?

Any information about that would be nice either.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://inchoo.net/magento-2/setup-scripts-magento-2/) from Inchoo , they explained M2 setup script very well .

Hope this be helpful for you .